# Accusative vs Ergative

Tags: syntax, terminology, morphology, ergativity

In terms of syntactic structure, from the below grammar can we conclude that English is accusative language, not ergative.

> S --> NP VP
>
> VPtv --> Vtv NP
>
> VPiv --> Viv

By intuition, I believe it should be accusative but I am confused on why, and how?

Comment: Wikipedia says of [ergative languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative%E2%80%93absolutive_language) *...this contrasts with **nominative–accusative languages such as English***

Comment: @MaryAaronson What makes you think you have 'intuitions' about whether or not a language is accusative? Also, we can't conclude anything from the above phrase structure rules wrt accusativity vs. ergativity since there's no indication of case.

Comment: @MaryAaronson Wikipedia is pretty good on the ergative-absolutive vs. nominative-accusative distinction. Check out the link posted above and elaborate on your question if you're still confused.

Comment: The grammar wouldn't work, there's no way to arrive at the category S. And as P Elliott points out, case isn't involved in the rules. You'd need nom/acc marking.

Comment: @MaryAaronson: No, word order has nothing to do with it. There is a tendency to mark noun case with SOV languages, but it can be either an accusative or ergative case system.

Comment: Morphosyntactic alignment and word order are orthogonal concepts. Most languages exhibit free word order.

Comment: @MaryAaronson: And, by the way, you can't conclude anything from a grammar fragment. Grammar fragments are artificial constructs, not data.

Comment: @jlawler, word order definitely CAN have something to do with it. Word order is one way to mark case. The general definition of ergativity does not restrict itself to morphology.

Comment: Word order is definitely a way to mark grammatical relations, but case is a morphological matter, like tense. If a "definition of ergativity" doesn't refer to morphological case, it has nothing grammatical to refer to, however "general" it claims to be.

Comment: @jlawler, "case is a morphological matter". If you define it thus, maybe. But analyses that treat particles and other syntactic devices as case are definitely not uncommon. In either case, e.g. Wikipedia's definition of ergativity explicitly states that the ergative patterning can be syntactic OR morphological: "An ergative language maintains a syntactic or morphological equivalence (such as the same word order or grammatical case) for the object of a transitive verb and the single core argument of an intransitive verb"

Comment: @jlawler, 'If a "definition of ergativity" doesn't refer to morphological case, it has nothing grammatical to refer to'. But that's my whole point! It can refer to word order!

Comment: It can refer to the man in the moon, for all I care. One can of course give a definition for anything; but that doesn't change the phenomenon. Data first, wikipedia later.

Comment: @jlawler. Firstly, Wikipedia DOES provide cases of syntactic ergativity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative%E2%80%93absolutive_language#Syntactic_ergativity, and a google search for "syntactic ergativity" gives lots of hits, are you claiming that these are all wrong? Secondly, "the man in the moon" is a strawman argument. The simplest, most logical definition of ergativity is "S patterns with O". You are the one trying to give a convoluted definition that excludes certain kinds of patterning.

Comment: One assumes that S and O stand for something, of course. Perhaps S means "subject" and O means "object"? And "patterns with" is also rather vague. I agree that syntax can have ergative properties; there are [a couple of structures in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/ergativity.pdf) that pattern ergatively. But to talk of "subject" and "object" as if they were universals is silly; Accusative structures have Subjects and Objects; ergative structures have Ergatives and Absolutives.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a rather robust generalization called Mahajan's Generalization, which states that ergativity is found in "verb peripheral" languages (VSO and SOV) but not in verb-medial languages (SVO).

So despite the fact that ergativity is a type of argument-alignment, it does appear to be directly related to word order (or, perhaps more accurately, whatever the structural underpinnings of word order are).

References:
Mahajan, Anoop. 1994. The Ergativity Parameter: Have-be Alternation, Word Order and Split Ergativity. NELS 24.
Mahajan, Anoop. 1997. Universal Grammar and the Typology of Ergative Languages.  In Alexiadou and Hall (eds.), *Studies on Universal Grammar and Typological Variation*.

Comment: To say that "ergativity is found in verb peripheral languages" does not mean that all "verb peripheral languages" have ergativity. There is thus a logical flaw in your second sentence.

Comment: But it *is* directly related to word order -- I did not say that word order alone plays a deterministic role (it doesn't). But, (to the extent that the generalization holds) knowing a language's basic word order *can* be enough to know if it is possibly ergative. (As in the case of English: knowing it is SVO is enough to know it is not possibly ergative)

Answer (score 1):

English is (still) an accusative language, although the accusative case has only survived with some pronouns (me, him, her, us, them, whom). Thus, we still say “He (subject) saw me (direct object)". If it were an ergative language we would say things like “him (agent) I (subject) was seen”.

Comment: But of course calling those pronouns a "case system" is sort of stretching the concept beyond utility. English is syntactically accusative, beyond doubt; the categories of both transitive and intransitive subject are virtually always treated identically by the syntax. To the point, in fact, that the few [ergative structures that surface in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/ergativity.pdf) (like _-er/-ee_ and _the shooting of the hunters_) are matters of puzzlement when encountered by native speakers.

Comment: I do not accept that your examples have anything to do with ergativity. As you are surely aware, the English –ee suffix is borrowed from French –é(e), which continues the Latin perfect participle in  -atus, -a, -um. In Latin (as in other ancient IE languages) the perfect participle has an active meaning with intransitive verbs and a passive meaning with transitive verbs. The French and English words in –é / -ee continue (in pre-modern times surely consciously) the situation in Latin.

Comment: @fdb Ancient IE languages had both active and passive participles. The use of passive participles to express active meaning is a later development due to grammaticalization.

Comment: Ancient IE languages like Sanskrit and Avestan have active and middle participles formed from the present and perfect stems and perfect participles formed from the zero-grade stem, which are passive if formed from transitive verbs (e.g. śruta- ‘having been heard’) and active if formed from intransitive verbs (e.g. sthita- ‘having stood’). I am talking about real languages, not reconstructions.